# Should I keep attending interviews even though I've already secured a role?

Tags: interviewing, salary

I recently finished college and after applying at 10 different companies, 5 came back to me and wanted to see me for interview.

First one, I got a big fat rejection. 2nd, they only asked me 3 questions and again rejected. 3rd interview, the interviewer offered me the role right after I finished asking my questions (I was very happy).

Now, I've got two interviews on the way. I can withdraw if I want to but should I? The role I was able to secure is due to start in September so I still have a long time to wait.

What do you think?

Comment: Removed salary details from question - the bottom line there should be **which one do you want more** - simply the salary details doesn't mean much to us.

Comment: Have you signed or otherwise agreed to a contract which lays out your terms of employment (Salary, title, responsibilities)? No? Then you don't have a job yet.

Comment: The only good reason for declining an interview is that it conflicts with your work schedule at the new job you just started.

Answer (score 4):

Have you the first offer in writing, with a signed contract in place? If not, nothing is guaranteed and you should keep interviewing.

If you do, you have to decide if that's the job for you - if so, and you're not interested in interview practice, you can stop interviewing.

If it was me, I'd do the others - practice is always good, and you might give yourself more options.

Comment: More than enough people these days have trouble finding one interview with a decent company. There is no reason at all to pass on interviews offered provided there isn't any direct conflict with your schedule or current position (non-compete contract, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

**Typically you'd stop interviewing upon having a signed contract.** Until you do, you don't actually have a job - merely a promise.

**But your situation is different**.

It seems you were hoping to start right away. Instead of being accommodating, they decided to stall the entire thing until September. That's *several* weeks away. That's them telling you: "what you need or want doesn't matter; the only thing that matters is what we need." Just run.

It's one thing to tell you that you can start in a week. Maybe even a few weeks, if they provide you with a sane justification. Perhaps they need to sort out some admin BS, like securing a budget to pay for an unplanned extra hire, or making sure someone will be around to onboard you.

Telling you that you'll start "in September" while you're available today, by contrast, is *completely* different. It's disrespectful at best. At worst it can mean any number of things ranging from "we don't care about you" or "we don't value what you'll be bringing until you fit in this very specific box" to "we actually can't pay you yet but hope we will then, hopefully" of which the main variation is "we told you you've the job but it's actually conditioned on sales closing this deal with that client."

Assuming you've already nudged them to get an earlier start date and they refused, continue to job hunt whether you've a signed contract or not. The worst that can happen to you is you getting more job offers. And giving them an unapologetic "Sorry, I unfortunately couldn't wait until September."

Also, don't forget to set yourself a deadline to decide once you've a few hot leads, let them know when you intend to make a firm decision upon doing so - and stick to that date. (You technically have a date already: the day before you've been told that you'll start.)